# How to update with concat and if statement?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with contact codes. When contact code is not specified there are `^^` in the empty cell. If specified should be: `^Code123^,^Code321^,^Code987^`

I want to update this cell, but I dont know how to rewrite empty cell with ^^?

With my query I get this result `^^,^Code123^,^Code321^,^Code987^`. How to delete `^^` when updating cell?

```
$sql6 = "UPDATE contacts 
         SET clicks_c=IF(clicks_c='', 
                         '^".$url_name."^',
                         CONCAT_WS(',',clicks_c,'^".$url_name."^')) 
         WHERE id_c='".$row_id."'";
```

Comment: what is your expected result?

Comment: result with my query is ^^,^Code123^,^Code321^,^Code987^ but I want ^Code123^,^Code321^,^Code987^

Comment: This is a horrible data format. You should normalize your tables, not put a list in a column.

Comment: I don't see where `^^` is coming from in your query. Can `$url_name` be empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an empty cell contains `^^`, you need to test for that in your `IF()`. Change:

```
IF(clicks_c='',
```

to:

```
IF(clicks_c IN ('', '^^),
```

Then it will replace `^^` with a nonempty code, instead of concatenating to it.